# css complicated selector query

Tags: css, d3.js

So the structure of the code is

```
<div class="day_graph">
   <svg class='y_axis'>
     .....
     <text class='y_label'>
     ...
```

I left out close tag for simplicity. Basically I want to select all svg elements with 'y_axis' inside a div that contains 'day_graph' and the svg elements should not contain a text element with class y_label.   Can anyone help me with this?

Edit:
Sorry about the confusion. Solution with javascript is also acceptable to me. I just can't figure out how.

Comment: No, you would need to use javascript for this, unfortunately.

Comment: doesn't seem possible with the last constraint

Comment: Would the svg elements contain any other elements besides the `<text>`?

Comment: Sry guys, javascript is fine too. But how should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The D3 way to do this would be the following:

```
d3.selectAll(".day_graph > .y_axis")
  .filter(function() { return d3.select(this).selectAll("text.y_label").empty(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible, except for your final condition.  This cannot be done using css, you need javascript.

Try restructuring your html so that you add another class to all `svg` elements that don't have a child `text` element with class y_label.

Comment: How do I do it with javascript though?

Comment: Using jQuery would be your the best way to go.   You're selector for this question would be:  `$('.day_graph .y_axis').not(':has(.y_label)')`

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible ways of going about this:

**1) CSS Only** - If your `<svg>` elements without `<text>` elements do not contain any other elements i.e.:

```
<div class="day_graph">
    <svg class='y_axis'>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Then you can use the `:empty` selector to target those elements. Something like this would do the trick:

```
.day_graph .y_axis:empty {
    //apply style
}
```

**2) Javascript** - If that is not the case, then Javascript, in this case jQuery since I'm not all too familiar with D3, has to be used and you do something like this:

```
$('.day_graph .y_axis').not(':has(.y_label)').addClass('whatever');
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS has no parent selectors, unfortunately. You'll need to use javascript to do this. Here's a jquery solution(using the `has` and `not` pseudo selectors):

`$('div.day_graph svg.y_axis:not(:has(text.y_label))')`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/Br8Zx/)